# Suggestion for C++ compiler

Tags: c++

I am looking for a free C++ compiler compatible with Windows 8. Please add link of the web page from where it can be downloaded.

DEV C++ is giving much trouble. Turbo C++ is available for DOS operating system.

You may also suggest other free software that can run a C++ programme.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: turbo c++,code blocks are compatible with windows 8,seeking product recommendations were off topic here

Comment: I have downloaded a turbo C++ and can not install in Windows 8.

Comment: @Viewers Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Samprity - Its a product recomendation.  You don't indicate what revision of C++ you want to support.  Turbo C++ hasn't been relevant product for 7 years ( 2006 ).

Answer (score 2):

IDEs that usually include compilers:

1. [Orwell Dev-C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/2013/05/dev-c-542-released.html)
2. [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) [select the one with `Mingw`]
3. [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) [You may need to add the C++ package]
4. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) [You may need to add the C++ package]
5. [Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) [If you're a student, you may be able to get pro for free from [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/)]

Of course, there are always *just compilers* from/using:

1. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
2. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: Which one is best in your opinion?

Comment: I don't develop much in Windows anymore, last I used was Codeblocks (but that is no ringing endorsement necessarily) - if you do Windows specific work, I'd probably go with MS's options.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Visual Studio express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express). You can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Another Free C++ compiler would be [MinGW's GCC](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) compiler.

Answer (score 1):

[Turbo c++](http://www.windows8downloads.com/win8-turbo-c--edqfuffj/) 3.0 supports on windows 8 , apart from that [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) Suits for you ,Also if you have eclipse ide you can work on with [CDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)
or [Dev c++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) also be a good option.